# The development server returns response error code: 500

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement react native into my existing native android app. 
I added a ReactActivity in to my app.
It was running perfectly.

Suddenly it giving the error "The development server returns response error code: 500" into the ReactActivity
[image]

Here is my console output..'
[image]

I have tried by reinstall node and watchman.
I also tried by deleting the node_module folder.

Here is my ReactActivity.java class

```
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new 
Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }

        HashMap<String,Object> extras = new HashMap<>();
        extras.put("page_name","Football team");

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)

           .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED).build();
          mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);
         setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
```

Comment: Please update the post with your code

Comment: is running this command works for you?
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
usually above command solve my problem like this

Comment: I tried but same problem... I also tried with cache clean...